# Technique to detect where Javascript gets stuck?

Tags: javascript, debugging, developer-tools

I'm debugging unobfuscated Javascript code. At some point, the code gets stuck in some never-returning function or infinite loop. What's the fastest way to find this part of the code? I assume there's a better way than adding a bunch of breakpoins/prints.

I'm using Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: Did you really mean ***un***obfuscated? That is, "***not*** hard to read"? Or did you mean obfuscated?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I figured that could be important to know. Maybe that's the assumption:) I should have written non-obsfuscated, I guess unobfuscated means "was once obfuscated"

Comment: "Unobfuscated" is fine ("de-obfuscated" would mean it was once obfuscated), but there's really no need to mention it. By default, we're going to assume you're debugging unobfuscated code. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open devtools and wait for the code to get to the infinite loop, you can click the pause button in devtools, which will pause the code somewhere within the loop.

[image]

For instance, I wrote a page with this code:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    let n = 0;
    while (isFinite(n)) {
        n = n + 1;
    }
}, 800);
```

and ran it, opened devtools, and clicked the Pause button. It paused the code in the `while`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are really on a loop with the console opened, go to "Sources" tab, then click on the "Pause" icon. The code will pause and you will see where it is stuck :)