# How to find infinite loop bug in javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, debugging

Recently I've noticed that a site I develop loads CPU and eats memory up continuously, when user is inactive. It looks like there is some kind of infinite loop I've created in javascript.

Is there a way to find a function/command/etc, which loops infinitely without reading and 100% understanding every line of code? I tried `console.log` in most obvious places with no luck - those commands do not loop.

Comment: If it were truly an infinite loop, you wouldn't be able to interact with the web page, and the browser would pop up a warning that the page is stuck. So it sounds more like you have something running a frequent `setInterval()`.

Comment: [Technique to detect where Javascript gets stuck?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69925870) but as Barmar said, it's unlikely to be an actual loop. Open the dev tools and the performance tab - set it to record and you'd get a better overview of what is happening. It might be that there is some interval running or similar which is not a loop per se but does continually execute code. Or might be something else. At least it should give you an idea of what is happening.

Comment: There might be some memory leak!, This problem would created via either logical error, or non intentionally used such API, that cause memory leak, And both issue can't be address by compiler, or such kind  of tools (function/command/etc), Do what @VLAZ said, Monitoring is the best solution for this kind of problems... Happy Debugging!